# very confusing Java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException:

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, runtime-error

I have switched from my old hdd to a ssd and have also upgraded OS. I saved a copy of my project and downloaded Android Studio and thought that it would run smoothly. but i am getting a

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
    C:\Users\Gotta\AndroidStudioProjects\BrandShopping\app\build
    \intermediates\istant_run_split_apk_resources\debug
    \instantRunSplitApkResourcesDebug\out\slice_8\resources_ap
```

It also says:

```
   Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info 
    or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full 
    insights.
```

but when i try with --scan it says '''Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.'''

But when i try to run the app it says:

```
    * What went wrong:
     Execution failed for task 
    ':app:transformDexWithInstantRunSlicesApkForDebug'.
     java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
    C:\Users\Gotta\AndroidStudioProjects\BrandShopping\app\build\
    intermediates\instant_run_split_apk_resources\debug\
    instantRunSplitApkResourcesDebug\out\slice_2\resources_ap

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info 
    or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full 
    insights.

    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

but like i said earlier, the build is successful

I've tried different methods. I have invalidated caches and restarted but to no avail, i've also tried to search the internet for possible sulotions but i couldent find anything.

in my Gradle.project:

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common 
    to all sub-projects/modules.

    buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
    }

    allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

}
     }

     task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

And in my Gradle.app:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.brandshopping.brandshopping"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[5,6)'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

any and all help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Goto  Settings->Build->Instant Run and un select enable instant run.

Comment: If it solved your problem. Give an upvote.

Answer (score 1):

With this settings,it worked for me

Settings->Build->Instant Run and 'unselect' enable instant run.

Answer (score 0):

Just Un-Select the Instant run from the setting than build and un select the instant run.